# on successful registration redirect to a different page in php

Tags: php, redirect

I am trying to create a web site where the intention is that when the registration is successful redirect to finish.php else be on the same page i.e. register.php
the code is as below:

```
try {
          $mail->send();
          $msg = "An email has been sent for verfication.";
          echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msg');</script>";
          redirect("finish.php");          
          $msgType = "success";

        }
```

in the above code the function of inserting in db is completed. alert message is shown on the page but the page is not redirected to finish.php
my form submit looks like:

```
<form action="free_register.php"  class="form-horizontal well" method="post" name="f" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
```

Comment: just add `window.location='finish.php'` in your js code after `alert`

Comment: Thanks but, this doesnot redirect...it remains on the same page

Comment: @anonymous The website should work without js.

Comment: @user877329 i know but he is echoing javascript code, so `header` php function will not work, and will raise a header already sent error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use header("Location: dashboard.php")

**UPDATE:**

You have two options. Either redirect with js or php.

```
/* PHP */

try {
    $mail->send();
    $msg = "An email has been sent for verfication.";
    header("Location: finish.php");         
    $msgType = "success";
}

/* JS */
try {
    $mail->send();
    $msg = "An email has been sent for verfication.";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msg');</script>";  
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location = 'finish.php';</script>";       
    $msgType = "success";
}
```

Both examples work. If not, check your try block or clarify "what does not work".

Comment: Thanks but, this doesnot redirect...it remains on the same page

Comment: Updated my first answer.